# Съезжают комментарии в PhpStrorm

Tags: php, linux, phpstorm, fedora

Всем добрый день

Недавно перешёл на fedora linux и при работе в phpstorm заметил, что все комментарии, а также часть кода в среде разработки наезжают друг на друга.
Поиск в гугле особо не помог, может кто знает, как это исправить(скорее всего проблема с кодировками)

Заранее спасибо за помощь
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась после переустаноки PhpStorm